# Need help Implementing OpenID connect/ OAuth2 flow using React-native, Spring Rest Api and ADFS 4.0

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, openid-connect, adfs4.0

I have really hard time trying to understand mostly how should I implement my authorization flow. I think I have the authentication flow mostly correctly implemented using the technologies I've listed in the title. Here's what I want to achieve:

Basically I have a mobile app built using `React-Native` and I have made a restful API for this mobile app to use. I am currently at the point that I have implemented authentication using `ADFS 4.0`. My mobile app directly uses the `ADFS` endpoints to authenticate the user and I am able to receive the id_token and access token correctly from there. But here comes the part that I have no clue what to do next. Before I used openID, I had my own authentication and just an OAuth2 flow in my `Spring REST Api` and everytime I made a request from the mobile app to the API, I provided the access token in the headers, and used it to verify from the authorization server that the user is indeed authenticated and also received some crucial information about the user to use in my API. But now since I use `OpenID-Connect` and `ADFS 4.0` for the authentication, I have the cruicial information I need in my API in the `id_token`. The question is, what exactly should i send to my API now from the mobile app, the `id_token`, `access token` or both? Given the `access token` to the userinfo endpoint at the `ADFS` returns the subject of the owner of the token. Like is there any way I could receive the users info using the subject or what exactly should I do. I've tried to research this subject a lot, but I am still very confused..

Answer (score 0):

Send the access token to the API in the Bearer header. In the API,  validate the token and, if required, do user info lookup. A Spring example of mine [here](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.javaspringboot/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sample/plumbing/oauth/OAuthAuthenticator.java) if it helps.

Happy to answer any follow on questions ..